# Order and distribution SVG objects in all screen at load time with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I was trying to figure out the way to do the following: I have X number of SVG files that a page loads, and I have to distribute them over the entire screen, no matter what size the screen is, but the elements has to have the same size.

For example, if a single element loads in the page, it should be displayed occupying most of the available screen space as follows:

[image]

But, if a second element is added into the list, the screen should show them as follows:

[image]

But avoid this kind of layout for a single element:

[image]

And so on, I need to continue with that distribution, respecting the requirements mentioned above

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Anyone have any idea of how can this be achieved?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS-Grid
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

create a grid that resembles the maximum row/column cell combinations that you expect, and distribute the SVGs in container `<div>` elements.

You can define placement for each variant, and have the elements span the desired cells and rows: For a 12x12 grid

```
.single {
  grid-column: 1 / 12;
  grid-row: 1 / 12;
}

.double--1st {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 6;
}

.double--2nd {
  grid-column: 6 / 12;
  grid-row: 6 / 12
}

.tripple--1st { 
  grid-column: 1 / 4
  grid-row: 1 / 4
}

...
```

You can either prepare that list and assign class names like above, or compute the `grid-column` and `grid-column` values and just assign them with JS dynamically.